# How to select five values of a column with the top 5 in their corresponding row?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two columns `date` and `norder` in my SQL table `orders`. We have to select dates with the top 10 maximum orders. We can do this like

```
SELECT date
FROM orders
ORDER BY norder DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

But we want to order these 10 dates such that the date is in descending order on values that have the same `norder`. How should we do this?

Comment: ```ORDER BY `norder` DESC, `date` DESC``` would do the magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do.

```
SELECT date
FROM orders
ORDER BY order DESC, date DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions.

```sql
select a.date from 
(select date,dense_rank() over (order by norder desc) as rank
from orders
order by rank desc) as a
where rank <= 10
order by date desc;
```

This would give you the dates for the top 10 maximum orders (including dates for orders where the maximums are identical).

Comment: Although this *might* acutally work (really can't tell, didn't want to waste time dissecting it) it is incredibly unreadable.

Comment: It's pretty simple, in all other cases mentioned above, OP won't get the actual top 10 dates if there are order values which are equal. For example, if max order is 100 and there are 11 dates for it, only 10 will be shown by the other queries. With window functions, you get all 11, which rightly you should consider!

Comment: In short, we rank dates based on the norder value, and pick the top 10 ranks.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP(10) [date]
FROM [orders]
ORDER BY [order] DESC, [date] DESC;
```